# Android custom adapter : ViewHolder throw a java.lang.Nullpointerexception

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have an activity (ChoozQr2) that shows a listview with a custom adapter in a separate class (ChoozQr2Adapter). In that custom adapter, I have 2 timepickers and some code that describe the behavior between those 2 timepickers. The problem is: this behavior works only for the last item in the listview.
I have read several post and try to recently add a viewholder but now it throws a java.lang.Nullpointerexception on the private static class ViewHolder at the end of the custom adapter activity (see 2).

Your help is really appreciated !

Here is my last code
1. Code for the activity with the listview that call the adapter :

```
public class ChoozQr2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button fini;    
ListView lv;
Context context;
ChoozQr2Adapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> resultArr;
TextView tvNomDuQr;
NumberPicker npNbJours,OccAlarme;
DatePicker dateFirstOcc;
TimePicker StartTime, StopTime;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.choozqr_step2);

    //declarations
    fini = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fini);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    fini.setOnClickListener(this);

    //retrieve data from choozqr
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String[] sTemp = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");     
    resultArr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sTemp));

    //set up adapter
    adapter = new ChoozQr2Adapter(this, R.layout.choozqr_step2_textview, resultArr,new BtnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBtnClick(int position) {
            resultArr.add(resultArr.get(position));
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);             
        }
    });

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);  
}
(...)
```

2. Code for Custom adapter :

   ```
   public class ChoozQr2Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { 
   private final List<String> list;    
   BtnClickListener mClickListener = null; 
   TimePicker StartTime,StopTime;
   DatePicker dateFirstOcc;
   NumberPicker npNbJours, OccAlarme;
   TextView tvNomDuQr;
   Button Btn1,Btn2;
   boolean OccAlarmeNotChanged = true;
   ViewHolder holder;



   public ChoozQr2Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items,BtnClickListener listener) {
       super(context, resource, items);
       list = items;
       mClickListener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
       View v = convertView;

       if (v == null) {
           LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
           v = vi.inflate(R.layout.choozqr_step2_textview, parent, false);

           ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();    

           holder.tvNomDuQr=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.NomQr);
           holder.npNbJours=(NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerOccurence);
           holder.OccAlarme=(NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.OccAlarme);
           holder.dateFirstOcc=(DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1erJour);
           holder.StartTime=(TimePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.timePickerHeureDebut);
           holder.StopTime=(TimePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.timePickerHeureFin);
           holder.Btn1=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);

           //Btn1      
           holder.Btn1.setTag(position);
           holder.Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   if(mClickListener != null)
                       mClickListener.onBtnClick((Integer) v.getTag());                
               }
           });


           //initialisations time&date picker
           Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
           now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
           holder.StartTime.setIs24HourView(true);
           holder.StopTime.setIs24HourView(true);  


           //When StartTime is changed and is equal to stopTime, put the StopTime one hour later
           holder.StartTime.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener(){
               public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker v, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                   ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();                
                   holder.StopTime.setCurrentHour(holder.StartTime.getCurrentHour()+1);
                   holder.StopTime.setCurrentMinute(holder.StartTime.getCurrentMinute());
               }});

           holder.OccAlarme.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onValueChange(NumberPicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                   OccAlarmeNotChanged=false;
               }
           });

           //When StopTime changes...
           holder.StopTime.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener(){
               public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker v, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                   ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

                   //...and is equal to startTime, put the StartTime one hour earlier
                   if(holder.StartTime.getCurrentHour().equals(holder.StopTime.getCurrentHour())){
                       holder.StartTime.setCurrentHour(holder.StartTime.getCurrentHour()+1);
                   }               

                   //...and OccAlarme has not been set by user already
                   if(OccAlarmeNotChanged){
                       //Then OccAlarme is updated to half time between start and end time
                       int i = (Math.abs((holder.StartTime.getCurrentHour() - holder.StopTime.getCurrentHour())))*30;
                       holder.OccAlarme.setValue(i);
                       holder.OccAlarme.setMaxValue(2*i);
                   }
               }});            

           v.setTag(holder);  // set tag on view           

       } else { 
           holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();           
       }                       
       return v;
   }    
   private static class ViewHolder {
       private TextView tvNomDuQr;
       private NumberPicker npNbJours;
       private NumberPicker OccAlarme;     
       private TimePicker StartTime;
       private TimePicker StopTime;
       private DatePicker dateFirstOcc;
       private Button Btn1;
       //private Button Btn2;
   }
   }
   ```

And this is the logcat :

```
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): Process: fr.XXX.XXX, PID: 20161
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at fr.XXX.XXX.ChoozQr2Adapter$ViewHolder.access$12(ChoozQr2Adapter.java:193)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at fr.XXX.XXX.ChoozQr2Adapter$4.onTimeChanged(ChoozQr2Adapter.java:132)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.TimePicker.onTimeChanged(TimePicker.java:656)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.TimePicker.access$300(TimePicker.java:62)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.TimePicker$2.onValueChange(TimePicker.java:167)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:1835)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java:1621)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.scrollBy(NumberPicker.java:1107)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.onTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java:889)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7837)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.dispatchTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java:946)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2075)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1522)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2023)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8017)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3966)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3845)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3405)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3455)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3424)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3531)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3432)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3588)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3405)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3455)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3424)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3432)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3405)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5554)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5534)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5505)
07-02 09:38:22.743: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5634)
```

Comment: Usually, when you get errors like this, you should post your logcat message so that we can help find what is causing the error. Generally, `NullPointerException` means that you are referencing something that hasn't been assigned - i.e. it is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. NullPointerException depends what I touch. It happens when I touch the TimePicker StartTime or StopTime on respective lines of the private static class ViewHolder (see the 11 last lines of custom adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is viewholder as you have taken same name many times so just change your adapter by below code,

```
     public class ChoozQr2Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
     { 
         private final List<String> list;    
         BtnClickListener mClickListener = null; 
         boolean OccAlarmeNotChanged = true;


         public ChoozQr2Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items,BtnClickListener listener) {
              super(context, resource, items);
              list = items;
              mClickListener = listener;
         }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

          ViewHolder holder = null;
          View v = convertView;

          if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
               v = vi.inflate(R.layout.choozqr_step2_textview, parent, false);

               holder = new ViewHolder();    

               holder.tvNomDuQr=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.NomQr);
               holder.npNbJours=(NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerOccurence);
               holder.OccAlarme=(NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.OccAlarme);
               holder.dateFirstOcc=(DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1erJour);
               holder.StartTime=(TimePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.timePickerHeureDebut);
               holder.StopTime=(TimePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.timePickerHeureFin);
               holder.Btn1=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);               

             v.setTag(holder);  // set tag on view           

           } 
           else { 
             holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();           
           }      


    //Btn1      
    holder.Btn1.setTag(position);
    holder.Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mClickListener != null)
                mClickListener.onBtnClick((Integer) v.getTag());                
        }
    });


    //initialisations time&date picker
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    holder.StartTime.setIs24HourView(true);
    holder.StopTime.setIs24HourView(true);  


    //When StartTime is changed and is equal to stopTime, put the StopTime one hour later
    holder.StartTime.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener(){
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker v, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            ViewHolder selectedHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();                
            selectedHolder.StopTime.setCurrentHour(selectedHolder.StartTime.getCurrentHour()+1);
            selectedHolder.StopTime.setCurrentMinute(selectedHolder.StartTime.getCurrentMinute());
        }});

    holder.OccAlarme.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            OccAlarmeNotChanged=false;
        }
    });

    //When StopTime changes...
    holder.StopTime.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener(){
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker v, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            ViewHolder selectedHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

            //...and is equal to startTime, put the StartTime one hour earlier
            if(selectedHolder.StartTime.getCurrentHour().equals(selectedHolder.StopTime.getCurrentHour())){
                selectedHolder.StartTime.setCurrentHour(selectedHolder.StartTime.getCurrentHour()+1);
            }               

            //...and OccAlarme has not been set by user already
            if(OccAlarmeNotChanged){
                //Then OccAlarme is updated to half time between start and end time
                int i = (Math.abs((selectedHolder.StartTime.getCurrentHour() - selectedHolder.StopTime.getCurrentHour())))*30;
                selectedHolder.OccAlarme.setValue(i);
                selectedHolder.OccAlarme.setMaxValue(2*i);
            }
        }});      

    return v;
 }    

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView tvNomDuQr;
        private NumberPicker npNbJours;
        private NumberPicker OccAlarme;     
        private TimePicker StartTime;
        private TimePicker StopTime;
        private DatePicker dateFirstOcc;
        private Button Btn1;
        //private Button Btn2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately it throws the same error...
another idea ?